# Issues updating Heroku to a newer version on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide, failed-installation

I've been having trouble trying to update to the latest version of Heroku on Cloud9 as you can see here:

```
        ~/workspace/hello_app (master): $ heroku version
        heroku-toolbelt/3.31.3 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.1.5
        You have no installed plugins.
        WARNING: Toolbelt v3.37.6 update available.
```

But when I try to update it, this is what I got:

```
        ~/workspace/hello_app (master):$ heroku update
        !    To update this version of the Heroku client please use
        !    `apt-get install heroku-toolbelt`
```

Then I tried typing in 'apt-get install heroku-toolbelt' into my terminal and this was the result:

```
       ~/workspace/hello_app (master): $ apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
       E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
       E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I have also tried to install Heroku Toolbelt using https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ , but I still seem to get the same warning that you see with the first code above telling me that I need to update it to v 3.37.6 . I'm sorry for this newbie mistake, but is there anyone out there that can help me resolve this little issue, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```

Comment: Although this did update the toolbelt, I didn;t update it to the latest version. For this, it was necessary to run `wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`.

Comment: I came here because i was trying to get the heroku logs and i got this error:
 !    Please specify a version along with Heroku's API MIME type. For example, `Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3`.
the update solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Cloud9 we don't have support for deployment from the UI yet unfortunately.

You can manually install various command-line tools into your workspace and deploy using the command line. It should go without saying that this is for developers that aren't afraid of the command line.

https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/deploying-via-cli

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and it got resolved by this..

- $ **heroku login**
- $ **heroku version**
  heroku-toolbelt/3.37.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.1
  You have no installed plugins.
- $ **heroku plugins:update**
- $ ***heroku plugins:install***
    Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
    Setting up node-v4.1.2... done
    Installing core plugins heroku-cli-addons, heroku-apps, heroku-fork,      heroku-git, heroku-local, heroku-run, heroku-status... done
  ▸    Missing argument: NAME
- **$ heroku version**
  heroku-toolbelt/3.37.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.1
  heroku-cli/4.25.2-beb750a (amd64-linux) go1.5.1
  === Installed Plugins
  heroku-apps@0.3.0
  heroku-cli-addons@0.0.2
  heroku-fork@4.0.0
  heroku-git@2.4.1
  heroku-local@4.1.4
  heroku-run@2.7.1
  heroku-status@1.2.2